# PayPal SDK causing "Order could not be captured" error after completing payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

OMG this PayPal system is doing my head in! I have the following code:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=MY_CODE_HERE&vault=true"></script>
```

Then this script:

```
paypal.Buttons({

  createOrder: function(data, actions) {

    return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
                value:    parseFloat( window.my_config.amount ),
                currency: 'USD',
            },
            description: window.my_config.description,
            invoice_id: invoice_id
        }]
      });
  },

  onApprove: function(data, actions) {

    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {

        console.log({ details: details });

        // do something here

      });

    $('#AJAXloadingWrapper').show();
  },
   onError: function (err) {
        // Show an error page here, when an error occurs
        console.log("ERROR")
        console.dir(err);
    }


}).render('#paypalWrapper');
```

It gets into this bit fine:

```
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
```

But when it runs:

```
return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
```

I get an error and it fails: (no money is taken)

```
Error
​
code: undefined
​
columnNumber: 55441
​
fileName: "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxx&vault=true"
​
lineNumber: 2
​
message: "Order could not be captured"
```

What does that even mean? This is an example of what I'm passing into `purchase_units`:

[image]

I'm so close to just calling it quits and saying "we are removing paypal".

**UPDATE:** In my searching, I keep coming up with people telling me that the issue is probably from PayPal that I'm using duplicated invoice_id's. I know that isn't the case, but maybe I'm passing it along wrong?

```
return actions.order.create({
    purchase_units: [{
        amount: {
            value:    parseFloat( window.my_config.amount ),
            currency: 'USD',
        },
        description: window.my_config.description,
        invoice_id: invoice_id
    }]
  });
```

},

Comment: Do you get the same error if you remove the invoice_id variable, or not? Do you have a reason for passing vault=true?  Do you have any error logging of an actual error from PayPal, with a more descriptive error or PayPal-Debug-Id? Check the Network tab or other placed in the dev tools console

Comment: @PrestonPHX thanks for the reply. If I remove invoice_id I get the same issue (thats the reason I added it in the first place). vault=true was just added in as it was giving in the example code. Is it not needed? The final XHR request I see going to PayPal before the failure, is **9e473911c35c9**. I'm not sure where you look that up though? I did have a thought this morning that it may be due to the dev site being behind an IP block - but seeing as the request doesn't even need to make a server call, it didn't seem plausable. As a test I have removed the IP block, but the problem still persits

Comment: @PrestonPHX  FWIW I've also removed `vault=true` but it made no difference either (I just looked up what it enabled, and I don't think we need it)

Comment: @PrestonPHX BTW I also tested paying with another account. Both are valid and working accounts, and I use them all the time to purchase.

Comment: Create a new REST APP and try with its live Client-ID

Comment: @PrestonPHX this is already a live client-id running in live mode :(

Comment: Yes but specifically create a new app and use that new one

Comment: @PrestonPHX thanks will give that a go. I've emailed the account owner to do this for me (I don't have access to his PayPal account directly)

Comment: @PrestonPHX I tried it with a new client-id. Same issue. Spent several hours back and forth with a PayPal dev yesterday, to no avail. Sandbox worked fine, but not live. Eventually we found that a private window works. So I tried clearing out my entire browser cache (and cookies), and now it works! What a total PITA (as I'm going to have to re-login to all my accounts now). At least it works though. He was just as baffled as me as to why it wouldn't work (everything looked fine their end). Anyway, thanks for trying to work through this with me. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future!

Answer (score 4):

OK so I'm really hoping my pain will help someone else in the future. I spent hours going over this myself, and then more hours going over it with a PayPal support tech. The eventual solution was to wipe my browsers cache. A bit extreme, but it seems to have sorted it. I wish I'd thought of that before!

Comment: Gotcha, sometimes when testing in both sandbox and live the cookies get out of whack. In the future you can search for "paypal.com" in your cookies and just clear those domains', not your entire browser cookies

Comment: Also as a general web dev rule when errors like this persist you should try to reproduce in more than one browser (e.g. Firefox and Chrome) to help isolate whether it's a server or client-side issue.

Comment: @PrestonPHX yeah I'm kicking myself that I didn't try that. I think I was getting so stressed with it all, that my brain wasn't working right! (I've been a dev for 20 years, so under normal circumstances I would have taken the proper route of testing in other browsers, clearing cache, cookies, etc)